# Receiving GDB error "Dwarf Error: Cannot handle DW_FORM_flag_present in DWARF reader [in module /xxx/yyy/executable]"

Tags: gdb, clang

I am using Clang compiler and created an executable with it. I am trying to debug using GDB. However, while initializing gdb with,

```
gdb executable core
```

I am receiving the following error,

```
Dwarf Error: Cannot handle DW_FORM_flag_present in DWARF reader [in module /xxx/yyy/executable]
```

Does anyone have idea about this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your gdb is too old.  DW_FORM_flag_present is a DWARF 4 feature.  Support for it was added to gdb in April, 2010.  At least, that is true for the GNU gdb.  I don't know when, or whether, this was added to Apple's fork of gdb.